# Knox SSO integration with Keycloak error - Required Subject Missing

Tags: security, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, knox-gateway

I am working on integrating Knox with Keycloak with OIDC, for the SSO and security functionalities in Hadoop Cluster.

I have congigured everthing, and now while accessing the Knox URL, it is redirecting to the Keycloak URL. After authenticating the user successfully in Keycloak, it redirects it to the Knox URL(which is configured).

But once it is redirecting, Getting the below error:

> 2020-11-11 08:13:48,098 ERROR knox.gateway (CommonIdentityAssertionFilter.java:doFilter(79)) - Required subject/identity not available.  Check authentication/federation provider for proper configuration.
> 2020-11-11 08:13:48,100 ERROR knox.gateway (AbstractGatewayFilter.java:doFilter(63)) - Failed to execute filter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Subject Missing
> 2020-11-11 08:13:48,100 ERROR knox.gateway (GatewayFilter.java:doFilter(169)) - Gateway processing failed: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Subject Missing
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Subject Missing
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.filter.AbstractGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractGatewayFilter.java:64)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayFilter$Holder.doFilter(GatewayFilter.java:349)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayFilter$Chain.doFilter(GatewayFilter.java:263)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayFilter.doFilter(GatewayFilter.java:167)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayServlet.doFilter(GatewayServlet.java:158)

..........

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required Subject Missing
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.identityasserter.common.filter.CommonIdentityAssertionFilter.doFilter(CommonIdentityAssertionFilter.java:80)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayFilter$Holder.doFilter(GatewayFilter.java:349)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.GatewayFilter$Chain.doFilter(GatewayFilter.java:263)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.filter.XForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilter(XForwardedHeaderFilter.java:50)
> at org.apache.knox.gateway.filter.AbstractGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractGatewayFilter.java:58)
> ... 48 more

Any suggestions will be very much helpful.

Thanks

Jithesh